# Netbean How do i save a File to a Path?

Tags: java, netbeans

`File heduiFile = ExportImage.saveCompoentImage(fileName, poker480JPanel1.getjPanel1(), poker480JPanel1);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\a.jpg"));
out.write(heduiFile);
out.close();`

i would like to save heduiFile to a JPG format. but i still can't get the image?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I do it is with this small Java Method (below) which takes the image within a supplied Swing Component and saves it to the supplied desired path and file name within the local file system. The image is saved in the format specified by the extension found at the end of the supplied file name. If the desired file name is to be `MyImage.jpg` then the file is saved as a **JPG** file. If the file name is `MyImage.png` then the image is saved as a **PNG** file with the alpha channel included. The method supports image formats of: **GIF**, **PNG**, **JPEG**, **JPG**, **BMP**, and **WBMP**:

```
/**
 * Saves the image contained within a Swing component to the local file system. If 
 * the image file already exists within the supplied path then that file is overwritten.<br>
 * 
 * @param component (JComponent) The Swing Component to get the Image Icon from (ie: JLabel, etc).<br>
 * 
 * @param saveToFilePath (String) The full path and file name of where to save the image file. 
 * The file name must contain one of the following file name image extensions: .gif, .jpeg, 
 * .jpg, .bmp, .wbmp, .png. If the file name provided does not contain a file name extension 
 * then .png is used by default.<br> 
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void saveComponentImage(JComponent component, String saveToFilePath) throws IOException {
    String imageType;
    String ext = saveToFilePath.substring(saveToFilePath.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
    String allowableExtentions = ".gif .jpg .jpeg .png .bmp .wbmp";
    imageType = allowableExtentions.contains(ext) ? ext.substring(1) : "png";
    int rgbType = imageType.equals("png") ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), rgbType);
    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    component.printAll(g2d);
    g2d.dispose();
    File outputfile = new File(saveToFilePath);
    ImageIO.write(img, imageType, outputfile);
}
```

And this might be how you would use this method:

```
try { saveComponentImage(jLabel1, "C:\\Pictures\\Some_Image.jpg"); }
catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```